# Share to download

Tags: download, share

**How to make a share to download system?**
Means the visitor must share the content on a social network to get the desired file.
`eg.W3layouts.com` I must share the article to download the file.

#### NB: No third party solution. I want to know how it work and create a new one

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I will just use Twitter as an example:

You would use a Twitter web intent to track the user's click on your widget to share whatever content you want shared, seen in this page: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events . Use the 'tweet' event to listen for when the user interacts with the button. When you've verified that this event has fired, call the function that downloads the file to the user's computer.

Another thing, take to Google before you go asking it on StackOverflow.

Comment: I googled it. but it's giving result related to 'share it '

Comment: @SayemProdhanAnanta what do you mean?